# Python: Finding the average stock value for each month

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, average

Basically I have a list of tuples that include a data and price, something like:

```
[ ("2013-02-12", 200.0), ("2012-02-25", 300.0), ("2000-03-04", 100.0), ("2000-03-05", 50.0)]
```

The function needs to find the average stock value for each month, then return a list of tuples including the date (month and year) and the stock price. Something like:

```
[(250.0, "02-2013"), (100.0, "03-2000"), (50.0, "03-2000")]
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def average_data(list_of_tuples = []):

    list_of_averages = []
    current_year_int = 2013
    current_month_int = 2
    sum_float = float()
    count = 0
    for dd_tuple in list_of_tuples:
        date_str = dd_tuple[0]
        data_float = dd_tuple[1]
        date_list = date_str.split("-")
        year_int = int(date_list[0])
        month_int = int(date_list[1])
        date_year_str = "Date: " + str(month_int) + "-" + str(year_int);


        if month_int != current_month_int:
            average_float = sum_float / count
            average_list = [date_year_str, average_float]
            average_tuple = tuple(average_list)
            list_of_averages.append(average_tuple)
            current_month_int = month_int
            sum_float += data_float


        sum_float += data_float
        count += 1
        current_month_int = month_int
        current_year_int = year_int


    return list_of_averages
```

It returns an average, but not the right ones, and perhaps not all of them? I have tried looking at examples on the internet and asking my TA (this is for a python class) but to no avail. Could someone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** Based on the suggestion, the if statement should now look like this, correct?

```
    if month_int != current_month_int:
        average_float = sum_float / count
        average_list = [date_year_str, average_float]
        average_tuple = tuple(average_list)
        list_of_averages.append(average_tuple)
        current_month_int = month_int
        sum_float = 0.0
        count = 0
        sum_float += data_float
        count += 1
```

**Edit:** Thanks for the help everyone! I've got the code running now.

Comment: please split out the semi colon line with `*_int`, makes it really hard to read your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lis = [ ("2013-02-12", 200.0), ("2012-02-25", 300.0), ("2000-03-04", 100.0), ("2000-03-05", 50.0)]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,val in lis:
        key = "-".join(k.split('-')[:-1][::-1])             
        dic[key].append(val)
...     
>>> [(sum(v)/float(len(v)),k)  for k,v in dic.items()]

[(200.0, '02-2013'), (300.0, '02-2012'), (75.0, '03-2000')]
```

A simpler version of the above code:

```
lis = [ ("2013-02-12", 200.0), ("2012-02-25", 300.0), ("2000-03-04", 100.0), ("2000-03-05", 50.0)]
dic = {}
for date, val in lis:
    #split the date string at '-' and assign the first  2 items to  year,month
    year, month = date.split('-')[:2]
    #now check if (month,year) is there in the dict
    if (month, year) not in dic:
        #if the tuple was not found then initialise one with an empty list
        dic[month,year] = []

    dic[month,year].append(val) # append val to the (month,year) key

print dic
#Now iterate over key,value items and do some calculations to get the desired output
sol =[]
for key, val in dic.items():
    new_key = "-".join(key)
    avg = sum(val) / len(val)
    sol.append((avg, new_key))
print sol
```

**output:**

```
#print dic
{('03', '2000'): [100.0, 50.0],
 ('02', '2013'): [200.0],
 ('02', '2012'): [300.0]}
#print sol
[(75.0, '03-2000'), (200.0, '02-2013'), (300.0, '02-2012')]
```

Comment: considering this person is a beginner / new to Python, this code is way too obfuscated.

Comment: @JeffTratner I disagree, it's perfectly commented with great detail. It is not way too obfuscated, and you don't have to cater for beginners in all your code.  Also please read the FAQ, that is not a valid reason to down vote. +1 for this

Comment: @jamylak you didn't see this in the original version, which was only the first 6 lines.

Answer (score 1):

I'm never sure with homework problems, but how about I get you part of the way there by using a dict. I've tried to keep the example simple so it's easy to understand what's going on.

```
monthly_prices = {}
for dd_tuple in list_of_tuples:
    date, price = dd_tuple
    year, month, _ = date.split("-")
    # this will be a list
    curr_prices = monthly_prices.setdefault((year, month), [])
    curr_prices.append(price)
```

This gets you a mapping of `(year, month)` tuples to a list of prices. Try going from there.

`setdefault` checks whether a key already exists in the mapping and if it doesn't, sets the key to have the default value. (a `defaultdict` is in essence some nice syntactic sugar around this and avoids having to initialize a list on every iteration).

Comment: I'm still quite a beginner with python, so I have never used dicts before. I'm guessing it works like the append function if it joins elements together? Or is it like a place holder where I will add the prices later? I imagine it is possible to do this problem without dicts? I wouldn't want to force a lesson out of you :)

Comment: @MerandaFairchild I simplified the example to use a dict instead. Hopefully this makes it clearer what is going on (get the year and price, add it to the list of prices you are building). The nice thing about this is it doesn't require anything to be sorted.

Comment: Everything makes sense until the 6th row where I get lost a little bit. curr_prices is assigned to the current year and month and a blank list? And in the next row the price is added in. But I can't quite figure out what set defaults does (honestly I'm not even sure what a key is?). So this basically clean up the list and puts it in a dictionary so I can do the average, right?

Comment: @MerandaFairchild honestly, that is a longer explanation than would fit here. monthly_prices is a dictionary, which has keys that are month_year. Each one holds a list, and you add entries to that list each time. You can see [the Python tutorial on dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

Let's add a duplicate date to your example, so we can actually see some averaging:

```
l = [ ("2013-02-12", 200.0), ("2012-02-25", 300.0), ("2000-03-04", 100.0), ("2000-03-05", 50.0), ("2013-02-12", 100.0)]
```

"2013-02-12" shows up twice, totalling 300.0, so should average out to 150.0

I don't know if you've learned about dictionaries or better yet, defaultdict, but that's what I'm using. With defaultdict, you can specify in the constructor what should be returned if the key isn't found:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = default_dict(float) # we'll use this to keep a running sum per date
d_count = default_dict(int) # this one will keep track of how many times the date shows up
```

We could also use a collections.Counter to keep count, but we'd have to iterate over the list an extra time, which isn't great for speed with a huge list.

Now you'll want to go over the list, and add the values to the dictionary using the date as the key:

```
for k,v in l:
    d[k] += v # add the value
    d_count[k] += 1 # increment the count
```

So you should now have two dictionaries, that look like this:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {'2013-02-12': 300.0, '2012-02-25': 300.0, '2000-03-05': 50.0, '2000-03-04': 100.0})

>>> d_count
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'2013-02-12': 2, '2012-02-25': 1, '2000-03-05': 1, '2000-03-04': 1})
```

Now, since both dictionaries have the same keys, you can iterate over the items in the dictionary, and divide the value for a date by the count for that date, to give you the average by date.

```
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    d[k] /= d_count[k]
```

"d" should now contain your final averages by date:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {'2013-02-12': 150.0, '2012-02-25': 300.0, '2000-03-05': 50.0, '2000-03-04': 100.0})

>>> d['2013-02-12']
150.0

>>> for k,v in d.iteritems():
print k, v

2013-02-12 150.0
2012-02-25 300.0
2000-03-05 50.0
2000-03-04 100.0
```

Comment: This finds the average for each day, correct? If I manipulated the date so it was just month and year could I use a program like this to calculate a monthly average. Also if I need one final list could I use the last iteration (for k,v in d.iteritems():) change k,v to a tuple then add it to a list?

Comment: Correct. You could use Jeff Tratner's answer to make it a monthly average. If you wanted all Decembers' values to go in the same bucket, you could strip out the month and use that as the key with the same concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if loop the sum_float and count are not made a 0, so as a program proceeds the average goes for multiple months.
So try doing that and it should solve your problem.
Also one more point with your logic is that are you that whether your list of tuples is sorted one if not it can lead to complications with regards to your logic.

Comment: The list of tuples is sorted. So basically I need to reset the sum every time there is a new month?